# Get absolute-form request target of HTTP request using WAI

Tags: haskell, http-proxy, haskell-wai

The `Request` type provides accessors for the request method and the request version but not for the bit in between.

So if I have the following request:

`GET http://www.example.org/index.html HTTP/1.1`

I want the `http://www.example.org/index.html` in between

[RFC7230 Section 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2) allows for this when making a request to a proxy. Section 5.4 says that the `Host` header should be overriden by the proxy with the host in the URI if the request is in `absolute-form`. This seems good enough for me, I don't know if WAI would handle this correctly if a client was not behaving correctly and sending a Host header different from the `absolute-form` URI.

Alternatively, if this is not possible: I'd like to ask if there is a more low level HTTP library than WAI available in Haskell?

Answer (score 0):

The `rawPathInfo` accessor method will provide this. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:rawPathInfo for details.

If you want the query string too, it's available via the `rawQueryString` accessor.

As for the host, HTTP requests don't normally look like your example (HTTP/1.1 clients will only look like that if they're connecting to a proxy, rather than to the destination Web server). Instead, they often look like this:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
```

If you want `http://www.example.org` too, then you'll have to rebuild it yourself from the host and protocol information.

Comment: rawPathInfo only returns the path part of the URI. Not the query, and not the parts before the path

Comment: I updated my question. I wasn't very clear in my original question.

Comment: @Philippe So you're saying that the client is sending an absolute URI, and `rawPathInfo` doesn't show it anyway?

Comment: Yes, I'm using curl with the -x flag.

Comment: It'd be weird if it did. The path is only one part of an URI.